# Passing a dictionary to another function

Tags: python

I have built a function to create a dictionary and return it. This function is called `get_values`, and is structured as follows:

```
def initiate_values(directory):
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.[xX][lL][sS]')):
        title = os.path.basename(file).lower()
        if title == 'etc.xls':
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
            wb = wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')
            get_values(file, wb)    

def get_values():
    info_from_etc = dict()
    # build dict
    return info_from_etc
```

It works, in that it creates the dictionary and then when I try and print it, it prints the correct values. However, when I try and call this `get_values` function from another function, the dictionary returns as "None". This is my function to call `get_values` -

```
def packager():
    info_from_etc = initiate_values()
    print info_from_etc # this prints "None"
```

What am I doing incorrectly here, and how would I return the proper dictionary here -- that is, a dictionary that is not `None`.

Comment: This code returns the dictionary just fine.  You have something else going on in your real code.  Why don't you post the real code?

Comment: What you've shown us appears to be correct (well, except for the obvious typo). I suppose the trouble is in what you *haven't* shown us. Please construct the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates the problem, and copy-paste that here. For more info see http://sscce.org/

Comment: Works fine for me here. I suspect there is more to this code than what you are showing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `return` the dictionary from `initiate_values`:

```
def initiate_values(directory):
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.[xX][lL][sS]')):
        title = os.path.basename(file).lower()
        if title == 'etc.xls':
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
            wb = wb.sheet_by_name(u'Sheet1')
            return get_values(file, wb)  # added `return'
    return {} # or some other value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
info_from_etc = initiate_values()
```

`initiate_values` does not return anything, so by Python default, it returns `None`. You should be able to figure out where to put the return statement based on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you do need to return the dictionary in your initiate_values() function, but you are also giving get_values two parameters (file, wb) in the initiate_values function, and you aren't giving it any in the declaration. It seems that there might be a problem there too.